# How to use xbacklight with brightness keys in a VAIO

Tags: 12.04, brightness, vaio, sony, backlight

I have a Sony VAIO VPCCW15FL, with Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

Sadly, the brightness keys do not work out of the box, although the brightness meter reacts to the brightness up/down keypresses.

Yesterday, I installed xbacklight and tried it from the terminal. As a normal user (without sudo), I can run  `xbacklight -40`, for example, and the backlight dims. It works great.

I then opened the Keyboard settings, and tried to set up two custom shortcuts for controlling the backlight brightness. I named one as "Brightness up", with `xbacklight +10` as its command. Then I clicked to set the key, and "Monitor brightness up" showed up (as the key), so it was detected. However, even after rebooting, it didn't work. I tried changing the command to `/usr/bin/xbacklight +10` but it didn't work either.

What's wrong with this? Also, I would like to know if I can make the brightness meter use the xbacklight command instead of its default. Is there any file I can change to do this? I think that would be even better than defining the shortcuts since it would integrate with the brightness bar. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got to a different solution that should work for other laptops too, not only for VAIOs.

Make sure that xbacklight and inotify-tools are installed, I just ran `sudo apt-get install xbacklight inotify-tools` .

Configure the following script and save it as a bash script (for example, save it as backlight_control.sh), and give it executable permissions with `chmod +x backlight_control.sh`.

Then add it to your startup applications (can be done in 12.04 by clicking on the menu item on the top-right corner of the screen). The backlight level should be restored to its previous setting, and the controls should start working, **after you log into your session**. The brightness meter displays the correct value too.

I hope this helps in case someone else is having the same issue. Any comments on its performance or anything else are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script for setting the correct brightness for the backlight.
# Depends on: xbacklight and inotify-tools,
# Which can be installed by running:
#       `sudo apt-get install xbacklight inotify-tools`
#
# Author: Esteban Serrano Roloff <e.serrano.r (at) me.com>
#
# Tested on a Sony VAIO VPCCW15FL
# running Ubuntu 12.04
# 2013-03-27 (YYYY-MM-DD)

# Setup the correct paths (look inside /sys/class/backlight/)
current_brightness_path="/sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness"
max_brightness_path="/sys/class/backlight/sony/max_brightness"
# To find the correct value for min_brightness, make the
# brightness meter go to its minimum (by repeatedly pressing
# the brightness down key), even if the actual brightness stays
# the same, and then run on a terminal:
#       `cat /sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness`
min_brightness=0


#### No editing needed beyond this line (I hope) ####
max_brightness=`cat $max_brightness_path`
range=${max_brightness-min_brightness}



# Set the correct brightness level on start up.
current_brightness=`cat $current_brightness_path`
let current_brightness_pctg=100*$current_brightness/$range
xbacklight =$current_brightness_pctg

# Listen for brightness changes, forever.
while inotifywait -e close_write $current_brightness_path; do

    current_brightness=`cat $current_brightness_path`
    let current_brightness_pctg=100*$current_brightness/$range
    xbacklight =$current_brightness_pctg

done
```

Comment: Couldn't watch /sys/class/backlight/sony/brightness: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to set up the correct path on the `current_brightness_path` variable. I don't know what the correct path is on yout system, but take a look inside `/sys/class/backlight/`.

Comment: I don't know if I'm even in the right place, but this worked for my situation: Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, Acer eMachines e725.