# How do I fix the the brightness controls on a Samsung RV520?

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, brightness

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on my Samsung RV520 with Nvidia GT520M but it looks like my screen's brightness is set to a value close the minimum! Even though I can see the brightness bar increase or decrease by pressing Fn up or Fn down, or by trying to manually adjust it, it never really changes...

Answer (score 0):

There is command like xbacklight, but not all displays resp. drivers of graphics cards work together with this command. As I see in manpages xbacklight probably is referring more to intel-chipsets. But if your machine has an intel-processor with hybrid-chipset of nvidia like GT 520M ( mine here is GT 540M ) - this should work to use xbacklight cautiously as command like explained here at top of :

[How to use xbacklight with brightness keys in a VAIO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio)

Comment: My computer has an i5 Intel processor but that command doesn't seem to change anything, I've tried it with different "+"values but nothing seems to happen :/

Comment: @HarrySpotter - xbacklight as command is not installed by default - and it is dependent on xrandr ?! Have you installed xrandr ? After installation of both commands rebooted your machine ?

Comment: I have installed xbacklight a few days ago, but not xrandr, how can I install the latter?

Comment: @HarrySpotter - xrandr belongs to X-org files as I see. here is more to find for about Ubuntu: http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/ - xrandr was installed alongside with x-org-files on my machine, when I setted up x-org-installation because for drivers for nvidia-card.