# How to decrease the brightness in Samsung RV509?

Tags: 12.04, brightness, samsung

I'm using a Samsung RV509 laptop  with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Can anyone help me to decrease the brightness in my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

On laptops, you will often be able to adjust brightness, by pressing the <kbd>FN</kbd> button, and a specific <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> at the same time. Take a look at your <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> buttons. There should be small icons with a blue color on. If some of them look like they could be related to brightness, try it with the <kbd>FN</kbd> button. Sometimes it is also arrow keys and other buttons you will need to use.

If your keyboard looks like this, you can adjust your brightness by using the <kbd>FN</kbd> key and the <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys. Your volume can be adjusted with <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd>, and so forth.

Good luck.

Comment: Ya thank you my laptop is same as that and i used that keys only but it not decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xbacklight`.

- Install it by running `sudo apt-get install xbacklight` in a terminal.
- Change brightness by `xbacklight -set <level>`, where `<level>` is an integer ranging from 0 to 100 (lowest brightness to highest).

For example, to set medium brightness one would use

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

Comment: thank you all... but i installed xbacklight but its not working means brightness is not decrsing...

Comment: [Try This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio) Solution

Comment: or also try this 
`sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80`
<br/>change 80 by [0-FF] to get lowest-highest brightness
The value specified is in hex, so 80 will give you a 50% brightness

Answer (score 0):

first know the output name

```
xrandr -q
```

for example my output name is DVI-I-2

The brightness can be changed like this:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --brightness 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the options that are built into your keyboard give you trouble, which is often the case, you can use xbacklight. If not already installed, you can install it via the terminal with:

```
 sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

you can then change the backlight:

```
xbacklight -set [percent]
```

where the [percent] is a value between 0 and 100, i.e.:

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

would set the backlight to 50% of the max value.

if you want keyboard shortcuts for increasing and decreasing the backlight, you could assign

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

and

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

to whichever keybindings you'd like, using the "keyboard" menu and the "shortcuts" tab. These would then increase the backlight by 10%, and decrease it by 10%, respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but its not working in my laptop. if i open window it reduce in window but in Ubuntu its not reducing..