# Mapping xbacklight to brightness keys?

Tags: nvidia, macbook-pro, xbacklight

The default method of changing the brightness doesn't work with the NVIDIA drivers, and xbacklight changes it.

However, using the default mapper for keyboard shortcuts won't work for setting the F1 and F2 keys on my MacBook Pro. How do I set the brightness keys to use xbacklight?

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio) help in anyway?

Comment: @Ron That's for the Sony VAIO, and won't work on MacBooks.