# how to change ubuntu brightness?

Tags: backlight

i have repeatedly found it very difficult on desktops.
`echo 40 > /sys/class/backlight/` doesn't work as there are no backlight files. in laptop too sometimes there are not there but fn key works!
so i from where does the fn key change backlight when no backlight found?
i want to follow the same method my laptop is using and able to change brightness without the backlight file.
so for desktop it should be possible via an alternate method?

i installed xbacklight but it doesn't work as there are no backlight files.
i usually use desktop where i never ever found backlight files despite installing 6 distros.
this is the o/p of `xrandr -q | grep " connected"`

`VGA-1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 250mm`
 and this is o/p of `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5`

`warning: output LVDS1 not found; ignoring xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.` **so how to use xrand wihtout any errors**

and `sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80`
`setpci: Warning: No devices selected for "F4.B=80".`

and http://pastebin.com/gBSBsZ1w is o/p of  `lspci`
i also did `sudo setpci -s 01:00.0 F4.B=20` without any error since that is the VGA from lspci cmd. **but nothing happened**

Comment: You are trying to `echo ` into a folder. In `/sys/class/backlight/ `  there should be another directory , for example mine is `acpi_video0`, where you have `brightness` and `max_brightness` file.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed my nvidia video card driver and I changed the brightness from the driver's settings. Maybe you should install your video card's driver and then look there.

Comment: wait a sec, do u have brightness file on your desktop?? not laptop-which always has it and is no problemo

Comment: This is where I change the brightness: http://imgur.com/84S31uX